# Workaround for using functions in restricted system

Tags: oracle

I have access to an environment where I can run SELECT statements but cannot call functions. I know what all the code is inside the functions.

The functions are merely lookups (SELECTs and not INSERTs or UPDATEs)

Is there a way to simulate or declare the functions in a local context to get around this problem.?

Comment: Instead of wasting your time re-writing existing code wouldn't it be better to invest that time in getting EXECUTE privilege on the functions you need?

Comment: It's not allowed, company policy, will not change

Comment: Sorry but that's just insane.  You don't happen to work for the same company as Dilbert by any chance?

Comment: Has his company also only just ditched IE6 in the last year?

Answer (score 1):

If the functions are just doing SELECT statements then you can simulate them with an inline view ...

```
  select t.*
         , notaf.descr
  from  t
        , ( select code, descr from lookup_tbl ) notaf
  where t.col23 = notaf.code
```

... or a sub-query factoring clause ...

```
with notaf as ( select code, descr from lookup_tbl )
select t.*
         , notaf.descr
from  t
       , notaf
where t.col23 = notaf.code
```

--- or even a simple join (using ANSI syntax for variety!) ...

```
select t.*
         , lookup_tbl.descr
from  t
      join lookup_tbl
           on  t.col23 = lookup_tbl.code
```

You can use DUAL if the function does something computational (rather than a data lookup) but you may need to pfaff around with nested views to simulate passing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can declare functions in anonymous PL/SQL blocks but they're only usable within the same block and you can't use them in regular SQL. You can't use them in SQL executed *within* the anonymous PL/SQL block either. Only pre-declared PL/SQL functions can be used in regular SQL.

Here's an example of declaring an anonymous function:

```
DECLARE
   -- Declare an anonymous function:
   FUNCTION foo(x IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN 'foo: ' || x;
   END;
BEGIN
   -- Invoke the anonymous function:
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(foo('test'));

   -- "output_var" would be registered as an out param back the
   --  value of the function call:
   :output_var := foo('baz');
END;
```

If you're programmatically accessing the database (ex: using high level language like Java, Python, Ruby, etc) then you can use an anonymous block like the one above and [register the output parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter%28int,%20int%29) to retrieve back the results. This will most likely be a pain (and probably less efficient) compared to direct SQL usage but it *is* possible to execute anything and return back any value.

If you're stuck to using pure SQL then I don't think what you want to do is possible.